# Dynamic rightComponent in React navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I want a dynamic rightComponent in my react-navigation header bar. its possible to set the right component to a button in the navigationOptions of the screen but its not possible to change the disabled-prop of the button dynamically while the user interacts with the page.

**What I have tried:**

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
    return {
        headerTitle: "Pick images",
        headerRight:
            <Button
                title={"next"}
                type={"clear"}
                onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('Route')}}
                disabled={this.state.canContinue}
            />
    };
```

### };

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
    return {
        headerTitle: "Pick images",
        headerRight:
            <Button
                title={"next"}
                type={"clear"}
                onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('Route')}}
                disabled={this.canContinue()}
            />
    };
};
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.canContinue = this.canContinue.bind(this);
}
canContinue(){
//just for testing
return true;
}
```

It throws me the error that this is undefined. Did someone of you challenged the same and got a nice solution for that?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use it directly. You need to save it in navigation param.

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
    return {
        headerTitle: "Pick images",
        headerRight:
            <Button
                title={"next"}
                type={"clear"}
                onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('Route')}}
                disabled={navigation.state.params?navigation.state.params.canContinue():false}
            />
    };
};

componentDidMount() {
  // set handler method with setParams
  this.props.navigation.setParams({ 
    canContinue: this.canContinue.bind(this),
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer. I already tried this in a slightly different form. Your solution gives me the error 'undefined is not an object'. I modified it as follows:  `disabled={navigation.state.params?
                        navigation.state.params.canContinue():false}` And now it works. Didnt came to this solution the last time i tried to figure it out haha, thanks!

Comment: This was giving you undefined because it was binded only after the component rendered (ComponentDidMount)  so initially you were getting it undefined,